# HTML <select> item behaving in two different ways with same code on Razor page

Tags: html, css, razor-pages

I am trying to learn ASP Core and Razor by developing a simple project to present verb conjugations for different tenses to a user.  As part of the project, I have an options page at the start with a couple of dropdown lists (using HTML select components) to select the verbs to present and the order to present them in.

One of the dropdowns (the order selector) works as I would expect, i.e. it displays with a single value and a dropdown arrow to the right of it that opens the list when clicked (see picture below).  The other (verb selector) displays 4 items in a box with a scroll-bar to the right of the list and no dropdown selector.  Both use the same code and underlying data and I can't understand why they are behaving differently.  I want them both to behave like a dropdown (single line with dropdown selector to the right).

Does anyone know how I can get them to behave the same way?  Screen shot and code segments included below.

---

This is a screen shot of the two select components.  The verb selector is on top and the order selector is underneath.

[image: Screen shot of UI showing select components]

The verb selector has the following HTML (it forms part of a set of options and so has a radio input, but there is no interaction between these components. 
 I have commented out the radio input and it makes no difference to how the select component displays):

```
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="selverbs" value="sel" id="sel" onclick="javascript:topenable()" />
    <label for="top">Selected verbs </label>
    <select name="verbs" asp-for="selectedverbs" asp-items="Model.verbs"></select>
</td>
```

The order selector has the following HTML:

```
<td>
    <label>Verb order: </label>
    <select name="order" asp-for="selectedorder" asp-items="Model.order"></select>
</td>
```

Both selectors use Lists with SelectListItems in them.

The data for the verb selector is created like this:

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetVerbs()
{
    List<SelectListItem> results = new List<SelectListItem>();
    int rank = 1;
    foreach (string s in collection.AsQueryable().OrderBy(doc => doc.Rank).GroupBy(doc => doc.Rank).Select(g => g.First().Infinitive))
    {
        results.Add(new SelectListItem(s, rank.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)));
        rank++;
    }
    return results;
}
```

The data for the order selector is generated as follows:

```
[BindProperty]
public List<SelectListItem> order { get; } = new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "forward" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "-1", Text = "reverse" },
    new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "random"  }
};
```

I have tried setting size="1" on the verb selector and this has not made any difference.  This component still displays with a scroll bar (see screen shot below).
[image: Verb selector with size="1" still has scroll bar]

I don't think I have anything in my CSS file that would cause this difference, but don't know much about CSS so have included the full file below.  This is mostly the default file creat ed by Visual Studio when I set up the project with a couple of additions from me.

```
/* Please see documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification
for details on configuring this project to bundle and minify static web assets. */

a.navbar-brand {
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-all;
}

/* Provide sufficient contrast against white background */
a {
  color: #0366d6;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1b6ec2;
  border-color: #1861ac;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1b6ec2;
  border-color: #1861ac;
}
/* Body layout 
-------------------------------------------------- */
div{
    color: black;
    font-weight:normal;
}

select {
    margin-right: 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 55px;
}

#incorrect {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#correct {
    color: forestgreen;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* Tooltip container */
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: none;
}

/* Tooltip text */
    .tooltip .tooltiptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 120px;
        background-color: #555;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px 0;
        border-radius: 6px;

        /* Position the tooltip text */
      position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        bottom: 125%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -60px;

        /* Fade in tooltip */
      opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.3s;

    }

        /* Tooltip arrow */
        .tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -5px;
            border-width: 5px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
        }

    /* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
    .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;

    }

/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

.border-top {
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.box-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 .25rem .75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

button.accept-policy {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: inherit;
}

/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
}
```

I have tested this across Chrome, IE and Edge and get the same outcome each time.

Comment: That is how select fields display, if the `size` is set to more than `1`. I don’t see it set anywhere in your code, but maybe something else (like client-side JavaScript) is manipulating it later - start by checking what the actual element looks like in the DOM, using your browser dev tools.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I haven't set a size for either of the elements and have just allowed them to default.  I have tried setting size="1" for the verb selector and and it still has a scroll bar at the side of it and operates as a scrollable list rather than a dropdown.  I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: I have looked at the page source and multiple is set against the verb selector, but not order.  To test this, I have set multiple against order manually and it now behaves the same way (scroll bar on right).  I have commented out some JS at the bottom of the page and that makes no difference.  This is an ASP Core/Razor app with c# on the server so not sure where else this would be getting set.  Can someone give me some tips on where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this isn't a size issue, but a binding issue.  It appears to be caused by the binding for the return value (`selectedverbs`) in the page's associated c# file as follows:

```
[BindProperty]
public List<SelectListItem> selectedverbs { get; }
```

Because this will take multiple return values it is setting `multiple` against the `select` component.  When I changed this to `public string selectedverbs { get; }` then the `select` component operates as a standard dropdown, which presumably only allows a single item to be selected.